# Calculate the sum of the series based on a given number in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

The series: 1×2 + 2×3×4 + ... + n×(n + 1)× ... ×2n

For example, if you enter 3, the output should be 386, because (1×2)+(2×3×4)+(3×4×5×6)=386.

I've tried various loops, but that is not even close to the desired result.

Though, I'll post it here:

```
int sum = 0, n = sc.nextInt();
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum = sum + i * (i + 1); 
}
```

Comment: you need to stick a loop inside a loop, after all, you want to 'n' elements between the `+` symbols, and each such node itself has `n` elements that you multiply: You want to loop 'i' times for each time you loop from i=1 to n.

Comment: In your loop, you're only multiplying two numbers.  But in the formula, you're multiplying a different number of numbers together for each term.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).map(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(i, i * 2).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b)).sum()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not intent to resolve it for you, but you are missing that multiplication itself needs another loop for each of the number in the loop you created (from n to 2n).

I am giving you the solution, but hope you will try to understand it to realize where you missed it.

```
public class MyClass {
private static long calculateSeries(int n){
    long sum=0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

    // You are missing multiplication part in your logic.

        long mres=1;
        for (int j=i; j <= 2*i; j++){
            mres=mres*j;
        }
    sum = sum + mres; 
    }
    return sum;
 }

public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println(calculateSeries(3));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do one better and give you advice on how to approach problems.
Divide it into smaller problems :)

I wont give you the end result code, I think you wont learn much from it, but I will try to help you solve it + learn from it.

So in words - given number N, sum the results of the multiplication of all the numbers between i to 2i for each 1<= i <= N.

So what you want to do:

1. receive input N
2. loop on all the numbers between 1 to N - you did everything until here, awesome :)
3. sum the results of the multiplication of all the numbers between i to 2i - this logic is incorrect in your code, I advise you to create a function that do this multiplication, just call and sum it in the loop from step #2

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `O(n)` solution using a single loop.

```
int n = 3;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1, t = 2, m = 4; i <= n; t = t * (m - 1) * m / i, ++i, m += 2)
    sum += t;
System.out.println(sum);
```

output:

```
386
```

Details of each step:

```
i  t                       m  calculate next t value
-  ---------------------  --- -----------------------------------
1  1 * 2                   4  Multiply 3 * 4 to t and divide by 1
2      2 * 3 * 4           6  Multiply 5 * 6 to t and divide by 2
3          3 * 4 * 5 * 6   8  Multiply 7 * 8 to t and divide by 3
```

Comment: Can't you move `sum += t` into the loop header?

Comment: @shmosel You can move it after `i <= n;`. In that case, the body of the for statement is empty.